# Spring : Active Directory authentication fails when upgrading to Spring Security 3.2.6

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

**UPDATE**

It looks like https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2897 will fix the issue.   I used 3.2.6 and changed the provider to add

```
provider.setSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
```

and it started working.   I still don't know why it mentioned DaoAuthenticationProvider.  It doesn't do that with this change, either.

**END UPDATE**

I have a Spring Boot app whose web pages are protected by a login that validates against Active Directory.   Everything was working until I upgraded to Spring Boot 1.2.2.RELEASE which brought in Spring Security 3.2.6.

Logging into Active Directory started failing with the upgrade.   If I switch spring-security-ldap to 3.2.5, everything goes back to working correctly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

With 3.2.5.RELEASE of that JAR I get

```
DEBUG 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Processing authentication request for user: myuser
DEBUG 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=mycompany,dc=com', filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))'
DEBUG 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Found DN: cn=My User,ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com
 INFO 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Ignoring PartialResultException
DEBUG 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : 'memberOf' attribute values: [CN=Content Admin,DC=mycompany,DC=com, ... and more]
DEBUG 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@1a256d80
DEBUG 18702 --- [tp1586246816-18] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8ba0727d: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@30421acf: Username: myuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1kgfzfy7haxcu1skjarcd03sg6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

And everything works.

Switch to 3.2.6.RELEASE of that JAR and get

```
DEBUG 19234 --- [tp1586246816-18] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Processing authentication request for user: myuser
DEBUG 19234 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=mycompany,dc=com', filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))'
 INFO 19234 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Ignoring PartialResultException
DEBUG 19234 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG 19234 --- [tp1586246816-18] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'myuser' not found
```

It looks like it found the user in AD just fine, and then for some reason tried to use DaoAuthenticationProvider.   I don't have a DaoAuthenticationProvider as the security is just based on the user being in active directory and validated.

I looked at the changes from 3.2.5 to 3.2.6, but nothing jumped out at me that could cause the failure.

Has something changed that I'm not noticing between the two versions of spring-security-ldap that I need to account for now?

Here's my @Configuration

```
@Configuration
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .and()
                .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider())
            .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapperImpl nyUserDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new UserDetailsContextMapperImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("mycompany.com", "ldap://10.0.0.131:389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(myUserDetailsContextMapper());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

And the mapper

```
public class UserDetailsContextMapperImpl implements UserDetailsContextMapper, Serializable {
    public static final String DATA_SERVICES_ADMIN_AUTHORITY = "Data Services Admin";

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = Lists.newArrayList();
        mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, mappedAuthorities);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2897 will fix the issue.   I used 3.2.6 and changed the provider to add

```
provider.setSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
```

and it started working.   I still don't know why it mentioned DaoAuthenticationProvider.  It doesn't do that with this change, either.

**END UPDATE**